# 10-digits BigDecimal cannot be saved in NUMBER(10, 2) column

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, bigdecimal

In a Oracle 12 database, one of my column is defined with NUMBER(10,2). The goal is to store numbers like that one: 12345678.12. Actually, I can store a such number thank to Oracle SQL Developer, so the format is matching.

Through my Hibernate-Java app, when I update an entity containing the following values, it works:

```
1.12
12.12
123.12
1234.12
12345.12
123456.12
```

But with the following, I get an error

```
1234567.12
12345678.12

ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

It looks like a NUMBER(8, 2)...

The field is in an @Embeddable class, type BigDecimal, without any field annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class ClassA implements Serializable {

    @Embedded
    private ClassB bObject;
}

@Embeddable
public class ClassB implements Serializable {

    @Embedded
    private ClassC cObject;
}

@Embeddable
public class ClassC implements Serializable {

    private BigDecimal myField;
}
```

Is there any other things that can override my column definition?

Comment: you'll have to ma nually do an alter table

Comment: Post the DDL for your table.  Your test value WILL going into a NUMBER(10,2) defined field.  I'm guessing this is not what the field is defined as.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first number in the decimal type is the precision, the second digit is the scale.
From Oracle's documentation:

> You can specify the precision (the total number of digits, both to the
>   left and the right of the decimal point) and the scale (the number of
>   digits of the fractional component).

If you have 10 digits *before* the fraction, you need a `DECIMAL(12,2)`.

The error you see comes from Oracle, not Hibernate, so I doubt changing your entity configuration will solve your issue.

Comment: The fact is I want to store 12345678.12 which is (10, 2), isn't it ? So why Oracle can tell me the value is too large?

Comment: The documentation state clearly that `12345678.12` will work. If it doesn't work, then it means the number being stored is different than what you expect. You should enable Hibernate traces with `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace`

Answer (score -1):

Thank to @Guillaume F., I enabled the trace logging for log4j and I discovered that the error occured in an audit table which was not up to date. The column definition still was NUMBER(8,2) instead of NUMBER(10,2)

Comment: You should accept Guillaume's answer then (A) to give him the reputation he deserves and (B) so that your question comes off the queue of unanswered questions.